# Spring with both oauth2Login and Basic authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

currently I am trying to add OAuth 2.0 in my Vaadin Application that will work also with my login form. I read this [documentation](https://vaadin.com/blog/oauth-2-and-google-sign-in-for-a-vaadin-application) on adding OAuth for Google.

Firstly, I added required dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then I added `client-id` and `client-secret` both for GitHub and Google in application.properties file

```
# Github
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-id={id}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-secret={secret}
# Google
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id={id}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret={secret}
```

After this, I set up my Web Configuration file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class VaadinSecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGIN_FAILURE_URL = "/login?error";
    private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/";
    private static final String DENIED_PAGE_URL = "/404";

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/register").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/icons/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/images/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll();
                })
                .oauth2Login(oauth -> oauth.loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll())
                .formLogin(loginForm -> {
                    loginForm.loginPage(LOGIN_URL);
                    loginForm.loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL);
                    loginForm.failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL);
                })
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL))
                .exceptionHandling(e -> {
                    e.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
                    e.accessDeniedPage(DENIED_PAGE_URL);
                });

        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

And then login form

```
@AnonymousAllowed
@PageTitle("Login")
@Route(value = "login", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    private static final String GITHUB_OAUTH_URL = "/oauth2/code/github";
    private static final String GOOGLE_OAUTH_URL = "/oauth2/code/google";

    private final LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();

    public LoginView() {
        Anchor githubLoginLink = new Anchor(GITHUB_OAUTH_URL, "Login with Github");
        Anchor googleLoginLink = new Anchor(GOOGLE_OAUTH_URL, "Login with Google");
        githubLoginLink.getElement().setAttribute("router-ignore", true);
        googleLoginLink.getElement().setAttribute("router-ignore", true);

        loginForm.setAction("login");

        add(
                new H1("Welcome to Login Form"),
                loginForm,
                githubLoginLink,
                googleLoginLink
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
        if (beforeEnterEvent.getLocation()
                .getQueryParameters()
                .getParameters()
                .containsKey("error")) {
            loginForm.setError(true);
        }
    }

}
```

And this is what happens when I click on any of the anchors. It redirects me to the anchor link.

**Example:**
After pressing the GitHub anchor, it goes to `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/code/github`, which I suppose isn't the right behavior, because of this

```
        // Set router-ignore attribute so that Vaadin router doesn't handle the login request
        githubLoginLink.getElement().setAttribute("router-ignore", true);
        googleLoginLink.getElement().setAttribute("router-ignore", true);
```

which is taken from Vaadin official documentation. On this redirected page, nothing happens without OAuth happening. Hope somebody could help to fix this issue, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You define two different `SecurityFilterChain` beans: one with `Basic` auth and the other one with `oauth2client()` and `oauth2Login()`.

This two security filter-chains must be decorated with `@Order` to determine which is tried first.

The one tried first must have a `securityMatcher` to define which requests it applies to. In your case, a matcher on the `Authorization` header starting with `Basic`  seems a good candidate.

```java
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 1)
SecurityFilterChain basicAuthFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // process only requests with HTTP Basic Authorization
    http.securityMatcher((HttpServletRequest request) -> {
        return Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).map(h -> {
            return h.toLowerCase().startsWith("basic ");
        }).orElse(false);
    });

    http.httpBasic(withDefaults());

    ...

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
SecurityFilterChain oauth2ClientFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.oauth2Client(withDefaults());
    http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(ex -> ex
        // This is required for OAuth2 login (used during authoriztion_code flow, so BEFORE the user is authenticated)
        .requestMatchers(Stream.of("/login/**", "/oauth2/**").map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new).toArray(RequestMatcher[]::new)).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated());

    ...

    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I’m seeing is the URLs that you have configured for login links which, instead of sending you to the auth endpoint to initiate the oauth flow, are sending you to the redirection endpoint.

Spring Security comes with default URLs for oauth2 authentication **/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}** and redirection **/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}** endpoints (registrationId: github, google, azure, …).

In your case, the correct urls links are:

```
private static final String GITHUB_OAUTH_URL = "/oauth2/authorization/github";
private static final String GOOGLE_OAUTH_URL = "/oauth2/authorization/google";
```

You can of course override Spring’s defaults but I won’t get into the details. This [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-login-page) from Spring Security doc provides more details if needed.